# Multiple @page in CSS file

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have multiple @page elements in a html file? I'm looking for this method because of printing some files:

There are multiple invoices and each invoice have multiple pages. So, the margin for the first page of each invoice should have another margin (1in) to the top of the page compared with the following pages of an invoice (3in).

So, when I add @page first { the first page will have another top-margin, which is ok. But after a few pages of printing, there will start a new invoice which need again a top margin of just 1in instead of the 3in. But since this page isn't the first page, the top margin will be 3in.

The ideal solution is to have multiple @pages, so I could start a new @page at the start of every new invoice which will have a new @page first which I could give the 1in top margin.

Hopefully the question is clear and thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are printing a web-page which has multiple invoices. If so, then `@page :first` will only affect the first invoice. Perhaps you can use the page break facility of CSS?  e.g.:

```
@media print {
    body {
        margin: 2in 0;
    }
    .header {
        margin-top: -2in;
    }
    .footer {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}
@page {
    margin: 1in;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that your answer isn't solving the problem, because there is in my opinion no posibility to rewrite the top margin of the 2nd, 3rd etc pages. So, adding the page-break: always will result in starting the new invoice at a new page, but with the 3in margin instead of the 1 margin since that page isn't @page:first

Comment: P.s. I already use this option for starting every invoice at a new page, but the problem is that the first page of the invoice need a smaller top margin than the other pages of the invoice.

Comment: How are you setting the print margins? @page?

Comment: That is correct, I set the margins with @page and [at]page:first. This is working correct execpt the posibility that I need multiples [at]page:first

Comment: I changed my answer to something you could try which uses negative margins. I have not tested this.

Comment: I have tried this before I post the question. The content in the minus margin isn't visible because of the @page margin.